# Qt, cannot instantiate an object in a window's constructor?

Tags: c++, qt

How do I create an instance of an object in the constructor for a window?  I am generating three errors just by declaring a pointer, named objects, in 'window.h' and instantiating it in 'window.cpp:' 'Window::Window(...){...objects = new objectHandler(1)}'

```
window.obj:-1: error: LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall objectHandler::objectHandler(int)" (??0objectHandler@@QAE@H@Z) referenced in function "public: __thiscall Window::Window(class QWidget *)" (??0Window@@QAE@PAVQWidget@@@Z)
(file not found)

window.obj:-1: error: LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall objectHandler::~objectHandler(void)" (??1objectHandler@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function "public: void * __thiscall objectHandler::`scalar deleting destructor'(unsigned int)" (??_GobjectHandler@@QAEPAXI@Z)
(file not found)

debug\Phursik.exe:-1: error: LNK1120: 2 unresolved externals
```

I looked up the errors and apparently they have to do with the functions being declared but not defined by the class.  I am sure; however, that all functions declared in 'objectHandler.h' are defined in 'objectHandler.cpp' and Qt Creator even knows how to find one from the other.  I am quite perplexed so thank you for your help in advance.

From window.cpp

```
Window::Window(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent),
    ui(new Ui::Window)
{
...
    objects = new objectHandler(STEP_TIME_HOURS);
    ui->setupUi(this);
}
```

From window.h

```
namespace Ui {
class Window;
}

class Window : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit Window(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~Window();
...
```

From objecthandler.cpp

```
objectHandler::objectHandler(int stepTimeHours)
{
    this->stepTimeHours = stepTimeHours;
    head = nullptr;
    current = nullptr;
    tail = nullptr;
}

objectHandler::~objectHandler()
{
    current = head;
    if (current->next)
    {
        current = current->next;
        delete current->last;
    }
    else if (current)
        delete current;
}...
```

From objecthandler.h

```
class objectHandler
{
public:
    objectHandler(int stepTimeHours);
    ~objectHandler();
...
    largeBody *head, *current, *tail;
}
```

Comment: It looks like a mistake in the `#include`s. There is nothing special with instantiating objects inside a window's constructor. Do you use Q_OBJECT in your custom classes?

Comment: If you deliberately insert a syntax error (e.g. by typing in garbage characters) into either of those two functions (i.e. into objecthandler class's constructor or destructor), do you then get a syntax error when you rebuild your program?

Comment: "It looks like a mistake in the #includes. There is nothing special with instantiating objects inside a window's constructor. Do you use Q_OBJECT in your custom classes?"
I added in redundancy and checked the includes so I don't know why it would be.  I only use Q_OBJECT in my window class.
"If you deliberately insert a syntax error (e.g. by typing in garbage characters) into either of those two functions (i.e. into objecthandler class's constructor or destructor), do you then get a syntax error when you rebuild your program?"
I do not.

Comment: @user3732350 : could you post some of the more relevant code? For example, the header of your custom class, and at least the beginning of your cpp files?

Comment: I added it to the O.P.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it.  The issue below is similar except QT Creator automagically added my '.h' files to the list in the .pro file.  I just needed to delete the build folder and suddenly everything started working.

[Why doesn't Qt Creator find included headers in included paths - even though qmake is able to find them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20701805/why-doesnt-qt-creator-find-included-headers-in-included-paths-even-though-qma)